# AttributeError at /jobseeker/addskills 'list' object has no attribute 'jobseeker'

Tags: django, django-models, model

I am trying to make use of model formset in Django. Howwever, My Model has a foreignkey which I want to make use of request.user in the form to assist me in tracking the person that save the information. I am getting this error.

```
@jobseeker_required
def add_skills(request):
    template_name = 'jobseeker/addskill.html'
    heading_message = 'Formset Demo'
    SkillFormSet = modelformset_factory(JobSeekerSkills, fields=('skill', 'level',))

    form = SkillFormSet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SkillFormSet(request.POST)
        a = form.save(commit=False)
        a.jobseeker = request.user.id
        a.save()

    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})



class JobSeekerSkills(models.Model):


    LEVEL = (
        ('Beginner', 'Beginner' ),
        ('Intermediary', 'Intermediary'),
        ('Advance', 'Advance'),
    )


    jobseeker  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, choices=LEVEL, default='Beginer') 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modelformset_factory` returns a formset type so `SkillFormSet` is a formset type, not a form. Instantiating it will return a formset instance. Also, `formset.save` returns a `list` of form instances, not a single form -- this is the source of the error you're getting.

You need to iterate over the list and add the attribute:

```
formset = SkillFormSet(request.POST)
forms = formset.save(commit=False)

for form in forms:
    form.jobseeker = request.user.id
    form.save()
```